# like most program windows, ... -- I don't understand this grammatical construction

Tags: grammar

Example:

> Like **most program windows**, the Visual Basic Editor has a title bar and menu bar at the top. Optional toolbars appear under the menu bar. You can hide or show any toolbar at any time by choosing View➪Toolbars from the menu bar. Select the check box for the toolbar you want to show; deselect the check box to hide that toolbar.

How do you understand that phrase? Is this something along the lines of the expression ***all things ~*** as in the sentence "***She loves all things Korean***"? Then I suppose it should be *programs*, with an *s* at the end. I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might naturally read it as

> "like most program's windows"

i.e., like the windows of most programs.

However, it is actually correct as it stands. Compare it to

> "Like most car tyres, this one has grooves"

Even though it still would appear to be, "Like the tyres of most cars" & therefore "Like most car's tyres", that actually isn't the intended meaning.

The object is not 'the tyres on a car' it is 'a tyre specifically for cars' or 'car tyre'

Likewise, it's not actually 'the window of a program' it is a 'program window'

Comment: I found the text [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=cF2RgRZIicAC&pg=PT33). Seeing the figure above the text, I think it's more like "Like most other windows of this program". They just call windows of this program "program windows", and they seem to think of Visual Basic Editor as a window--a program window, as well, imho.